# How can I configure Windows 7 to not run updates without permission?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm sorry if this is a naive question. I'm new to Windows. I'm not used to how it works.

I installed Window 7 recently on my Mac via Boot Camp in order to play video games.

Tonight I was enjoying a game when my machine simply put a message on the screen saying something about updating and maybe "part 1 of 3" or something, and then rebooted.

There was no warning, request for permission, or opportunity to prevent it. The machine just restarted.

I had no idea that was even a thing that could happen on a computer.

If anyone could explain how to stop that from happening, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start/Control Panel/System and Security/Windows Updates

I would select "Download updates but let me choose whether to install them"

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows Update by clicking the Start button ---- clicking All Programs---and then clicking Windows Update.

In the left pane, click Change settings.

Choose the option that you want.

Under Recommended updates, select the Include recommended updates when downloading, installing, or notifying me about updates check box, and then click OK.   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.